# Cookie to prevent Javascript from loading beyond first visit

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have an "Enter Site" button leading to my splash page and I would like to to only appear on the first visit, not on refreshes.  Is there a way I can send a cookie on the click event of my button? I've found similar tutorials but nothing exact

Comment: I discourage splash-pages and clicking on buttons to enter sites for anything outside of the 'adult' category, and that's only accepted for decency's sake.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how you want to show/hide the splash page.

To set a cookie when a user clicks on an element, you'd do something like this, if I'm remembering it right:

```
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick =
   function() {
      document.cookie = "cookie_name_goes_here=cookie_data_goes_here";
   };
```

Comment: nice, thank you for that head start - this would be a nice feature for my site

Answer (score 0):

Just set it on page load:

```
document.cookie = 'was_here=true; expires=Thu, 15 Apr 2020 20:00:00 GMT; path=/'
```

Larger solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pCs = document.cookie.split(';'); 
for (var ii=0; ii < pCs.length; ii++) 
{
  var pCookie = pCs[ii].split('=');  
  if (pCookie[0] == 'was_here')
  {
    location.href='next.html'; // or whatever you want to do.
  }
}
document.cookie = 'was_here=true; expires=Thu, 15 Apr 2020 20:00:00 GMT; path=/'
</script>
```